# Redis Won't Start After Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I had Redis 1.2 running successfully on Ubuntu 10.04. However, I just finished upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, and my Redis instance, which I believe was upgraded successfully, will no longer start. Every time I try to start it, I get the following:

```
root@box:~# service redis-server start
Starting redis-server:
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 52
>>> 'logifle /var/log/redis/redis-server.log'
Can't open the log file: Read-only file system
failed
```

I tried taking ownership of the directory and the modifying the log file with

```
chmod u+w /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
```

but it didn't help. I also tried to completely remove Redis and re-install, but when I try to remove, I get this:

```
root@box:~# apt-get purge redis-server
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
```

I'm an Ubuntu noob, and could really use some help. What have I done wrong with either Redis or the upgrade?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind: must've been a temporary situation due to the upgrade. I rebooted, and everything is fine now. Thanks.